# How to write generic function for such GADT type?

Tags: haskell

If I want a function similar to `sequence` but working with any tuples `(a, b, c...)` I can write something like this:

```hs
class Gsendme1 f where
  gsendme1 :: f p -> IO (f p)

instance Show c => Gsendme1 (K1 i c) where
  -- I simulate here real missiles launching with a result
  gsendme1 a@(K1 c) = print c >> pure a

instance Gsendme1 f => Gsendme1 (M1 i c f) where
  gsendme1 (M1 x) = M1 <$> gsendme1 x

instance (Gsendme1 a, Gsendme1 b) => Gsendme1 (a :*: b) where
  gsendme1 (a :*: b) = do
    r1 <- gsendme1 a
    r2 <- gsendme1 b
    pure $ r1 :*: r2

class Sendme a where
  sendme :: a -> IO a

instance (Gsendme1 (Rep a), Generic a) => Sendme a where
  sendme a = do
    let ra = from a
    res <- gsendme1 ra
    pure $ to res
```

and then to use it like:

```hs
>sendme (Just 1, "hello", 1.5)
Just 1
"hello"
1.5
(Just 1, "hello", 1.5)  -- the result
```

Now I have an existing code that I want to adapt to this generic solution, launching tuples of missiles (a little bit comic example, just to avoid the real production code):

```hs
-- this is GADT
data MsgPkt (m::Msg) (d::MsgDir) where
  RocketMP :: MsgPkt 'RocketM 'AskMD
  RocketHitMP :: RocketResult -> MsgPkt 'RocketM 'AnsMD

  BombMP :: WarHead -> MsgPkt 'BombM 'AskMD
  BombHitMP :: BombResult -> MsgPkt 'BombM 'AnsMD
  ...
```

and I have a function launching them:

```hs
launch :: forall m. (MessagePack (MsgPkt m 'AnsMD), MessagePack (MsgPkt m 'AskMD))
  => Timeout Miscrosec -> IPv4 -> PortNumber -> MsgPkt m 'AskMD
  -> IO (Either LaunchError (MsgPkt m 'AnsMD))
```

and this code exists and works fine.

And now I want to adapt this code, and my launching function `gsendme1` from the class `Gsendme1` should process `MsgPkt`s now so finally I want to do something like: `launchXXX (BombMP WarHead, RocketMP, ...)` and to get the result as a tuple too: `(RocketHitMP RocketResult, BombHitMP BombResult, ...)` - generics will "generate" all instances for me following used tuples.

But the problem is that I don't know how to adapt the code with generics to my `MsgPkt` and `launch` function, starting from the modified `class Gsendme1` and `instance Gsendme1 (K1 i c)` and so on. A lot of different errors, like wrong kind and so on. No idea even how to do it: `launch` is safe function in terms of input/output types - they are the same but the direction is changed from `AskMD` to `AnsMD` and I don't want to lose this safety.

I thought that `f` parameter of `Gsendme1` could be `Msg` but then no idea how to link it with `K1...` in the first instance. Also kind: `launch` and the GADTs requires it to be of a kind `Msg`, not `*`... Really, no idea. Is it possible and how to achieve it if it's possible?

*the result is a function/method using the original launch function and returning tuples on input tuples without losing launch's safety and writing of tuples instances manually, but with usage of Generics mechanism*

**EDIT-1:**

Class maybe could be:

```hs
class Gsendme1 f where
  gsendme1 :: Timeout Microsec -> IPv4 -> PortNumber
           -> f (MsgPkt m 'AskMD) p
           -> IO (Either LaunchError (f (MsgPkt m 'AnsMD) p))
```

Comment: Somewhat besides the question, but: I'd have strong reservations with something like your `instance (Gsendme1 (Rep a), Generic a) => Sendme a`. There's a reason the standard approach is to use the generics for default method implementations, but then still add an explicit head-only instance (or anyclass-deriving clause) for each specific type. That would allow you to just write a manual instance for `MsgPkt`.